# Component is constantly refreshing (repainting)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, custom-component

I have own component which works in my testing winform app good but when I send it to my friend and he used it in his more complex app then my component is constantly refreshing, slow responding, ... I think that problem is in my component because older version works good. But I don´t know what I changed (it was many weeks ago). I must give him working version soon but I dont know how to fix it because I don´t know where is problem. Can you try [this component](http://www.4shared.com/file/1Ogj5ECB/file.html) and say if you have trouble with that. Or maybe look at my code ([calendar.cs](http://pastebin.com/mWWRxDKx) [calendar.designer.cs](http://pastebin.com/sSviWT6k)) and try help me find problem. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a red flag to me:

```
void panelKalendar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("panelKalendar_Paint");
  if (_viewType == ViewType.Week)
  {
    btnNext.Show();
    btnPrev.Show();
    lblMonth.Show();
    panelKalendar.Size = new Size(SIRKA_KALENDARE_WEEK, VYSKA_KALENDAREBEZPANELU_WEEK);
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

You are resizing the control during a paint event, which would call the paint event again.  Same thing with the controls, showing or hiding controls during a paint event would cause the control also to invalidate.

Not 100% sure, I didn't run the code.

Comment: It looks it help. Just don´t know why it was good (there wasn´t any problem) in my test app. Thanks you saved me :)